# Yarn install not working, getting "Other managers are not allowed"

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I just started using yarn package manager in one of my project. I installed yarn globally using `sudo npm install yarn -g`

But when I tried to install dependencies using `yarn install` I was getting the following on the CLI

```
info No lockfile found.
$ node tools/preinstall
=========================================
Please install / add dependencies via npm
Other managers are not allowed
=========================================
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

That's weird. Any idea why am I getting this? Is there anyway I can enable yarn for my project?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Sounds like something that preinstall is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was happening because of `preinstall` script. Thanks @Kevin for the answer, you saved my day.